# can't rotate svg>pattern>image in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, rotation

I can't rotate svg>pattern>image in firefox. My code works in Chrome, Opera and Safari, and I didn't try in IE.

Here's the example :

```js
function svgClick() {
  document.getElementById('circle-image').style.transform = "rotate(180deg)"
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black
}
.circle {
  stroke-width: 2.1;
  stroke-dasharray: 200 200;
}
#circle-image {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<svg width="58px" height="58px" onclick=svgClick()>
  <pattern id="image" height="100%" width="100%">
    <image x="10%" y="10%" width="20" height="20" id="circle-image" xlink:href="http://cliparting.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Free-arrows-clipart-free-clipart-graphics-images-and-photos-image-2.png">
  </pattern>
  <linearGradient id="gradient">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="   #40fffb " />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="  #33468b" />
  </linearGradient>
  <circle cx="27.2" cy="27.2" r="17" fill="url(#image)" stroke="url(#gradient)" class="circle"></circle>
</svg>
<h1>Click on circle to rotate arrow to 180deg<h1>
```

Comment: patterns in Firefox only support transform attributes at this time and not CSS transform styles.

Comment: can you suggest what I can do to rotate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to change from using CSS to using a `transform` attribute on your . Ie.:

```
<image ... transform="rotate(90, 15.8,15.8)"/>
```

The "15.8" value comes from (10% * 58) + (50% * 20).

```js
function svgClick() {
  document.getElementById('circle-image').setAttribute("transform", "rotate(180, 15.8,15.8)");
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black
}
.circle {
  stroke-width: 2.1;
  stroke-dasharray: 200 200;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<svg width="58px" height="58px" onclick=svgClick()>
  <pattern id="image" height="100%" width="100%">
    <image x="10%" y="10%" width="20" height="20" id="circle-image" xlink:href="http://cliparting.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Free-arrows-clipart-free-clipart-graphics-images-and-photos-image-2.png" transform="rotate(90, 15.8,15.8)"/>
  </pattern>
  <linearGradient id="gradient">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="   #40fffb " />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="  #33468b" />
  </linearGradient>
  <circle cx="27.2" cy="27.2" r="17" fill="url(#image)" stroke="url(#gradient)" class="circle"></circle>
</svg>
<h1>Click on circle to rotate arrow to 180deg<h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to define a pattern for your use case, but I found this question looking for how to transform a pattern. I'll add another option for the general question of how to transform a pattern.

You can use `patternTransform` to define transformations on a pattern.

```js
function svgClick() {
  document
    .getElementById('circle-image')
    .setAttribute("transform", "rotate(180, 15.8,15.8)");
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black
}
.circle {
  stroke-width: 2.1;
  stroke-dasharray: 200 200;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<svg width="58px" height="58px" onclick=svgClick()>
  <pattern
    id="image"
    height="100%"
    width="100%"
    patternTransform="rotate(90, 15.8,15.8)
  >
    <image
      x="10%"
      y="10%"
      width="20"
      height="20"
      id="circle-image"
      xlink:href="http://cliparting.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Free-arrows-clipart-free-clipart-graphics-images-and-photos-image-2.png"/>
  </pattern>
  <linearGradient id="gradient">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="   #40fffb " />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="  #33468b" />
  </linearGradient>
  <circle
    cx="27.2"
    cy="27.2"
    r="17"
    fill="url(#image)"
    stroke="url(#gradient)"
    class="circle"></circle>
</svg>
<h1>Click on circle to rotate arrow to 180deg<h1>
```

I'm using the same rotation numbers as [the answer by Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41358079/5452969), and the result might not be exactly what the OP was looking for. I'm just trying to show the `patternTransform` alternative.

More info on [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/patternTransform)